# Pass an object as a parameter and modify it within the method

Tags: java, optimization, memory

Let's say I got a `Map<String, String>` and I wanna remove all the entries that value contains `foo`. What is the best way to do it, in terms of optimization/memory/etc.? The four `syso` below are printing the same result, that is to say `{n2=bar}`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, String> in = new HashMap<String, String>();
    in.put("n1", "foo");
    in.put("n2", "bar");
    in.put("n3", "foobar");

    // 1- create a new object with the returned Map
    Map<String, String> in1 = new HashMap<String, String>(in);
    Map<String, String> out1 = methodThatReturns(in1);
    System.out.println(out1);

    // 2- overwrite the initial Map with the returned one 
    Map<String, String> in2 = new HashMap<String, String>(in);
    in2 = methodThatReturns(in2);
    System.out.println(in2);

    // 3- use the clear/putAll methods
    Map<String, String> in3 = new HashMap<String, String>(in);
    methodThatClearsAndReadds(in3);
    System.out.println(in3);

    // 4- use an iterator to remove elements
    Map<String, String> in4 = new HashMap<String, String>(in);
    methodThatRemoves(in4);
    System.out.println(in4);

}

public static Map<String, String> methodThatReturns(Map<String, String> in) {
    Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : in.entrySet()) {
        if(!entry.getValue().contains("foo")) {
            out.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    return out;
}

public static void methodThatClearsAndReadds(Map<String, String> in) {
    Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for(Entry<String, String> entry : in.entrySet()) {
        if(!entry.getValue().contains("foo")) {
            out.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    in.clear();
    in.putAll(out);
}

public static void methodThatRemoves(Map<String, String> in) {
    for(Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = in.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        if(it.next().getValue().contains("foo")) {
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is `methodThatRemoves` because:

1. In terms of memory consumption: it doesn't create a new map so doesn't add memory overhead.
2. In terms of CPU use: iterator has O(1) complexity for calling next or removing the current element.

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way *methodThatRemoves*, because it

- Uses almost no memory
- Creates no objects except the (lightweight) iterator
- Is extremely fast (doesn't use any map lookups)

I would not make a copy first though, unless you have an unmodifiable map or you need to preserve the original.

Comment: isn't that exactly what methodThatRemoves does?

Comment: yes how is this different aside from the equals, which is not what he wants anyways

Answer (score 1):

For me the best is the one with the `Iterator` - *methodThatRemoves*, because you don't create an intermediate Map and don't use `put` method.

By the way the first one : `methodThatReturns` can be faster because `put` complexity is O(1) whereas remove is O(n) in worst case but it will use more memory because you have 2 different instances of Map.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with `methodThatRemoves` because you are only performing a loop operation and checking for "foo" equality. The others do that as well as Object map creation and map clear/put operations. So you clearly have 1 method doing less.

Also if you want to reduce memory usage you are better off not creating an extra HashMap just to remove 1 or more entries. This is assuming you don't mind the extra computation to iterate the map.

If you really want to go more in depth, you should evaluate this using a profiler or some sort.